# Angular 6, Firebase Storage web Image gallery

Tags: firebase, storage, firebase-storage, angular6

I've got a problem with downloading URL during uploading an image file.
    I want to use this url to show this images from Firebase storage.
    Uplad is working, because i can see this photos on my storage on firebase, but i can't download it and show in my web

Here's a upload.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { GalleryImage } from '../models/galleryImage.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { Upload } from '../models/upload.model';
import * as  firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  private basePath = '/uploads';
  private uploads: FirebaseListObservable<GalleryImage[]>;

  constructor(private ngFire: AngularFireModule, public db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  uploadFile(upload: Upload) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`)
      .put(upload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      // three observers
      // 1.) state_changed observer
      (snapshot) => {
        // upload in progress
        upload.progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log(upload.progress);
      },
      // 2.) error observer
      (error) => {
        // upload failed
        console.log(error);
      },
      // 3.) success observer
      (): any => {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
          upload.url = downloadURL;
          console.log('FirstURL', downloadURL);
          console.log('SecondURL', upload.url);
          this.saveFileData(upload);
        });
      }

    );
  }
   private saveFileData(upload: Upload) {
     this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(upload);
     console.log('File saved at' + upload.url);
   }
}
```

Here's my image.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { GalleryImage } from '../models/galleryImage.model';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class ImageService {
  private uid: string;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth !== undefined && auth !== null) {
        this.uid = auth.uid;
      }
    });
  }

  getImages(): Observable<GalleryImage[]> {
    return this.db.list('uploads').valueChanges();
  }

  getImage(key: string) {
    return firebase.database().ref('uploads/' + key).once('value')
    .then((snap) => snap.val());
  }
}
```

Here's my upload.model.ts

```
 export class Upload {
    $key: string;
    file: File;
    url: string;
    progress: number;
    createdOn: Date = new Date();
    name: string;

    constructor(file: File) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will be much more successful getting help if you provide your code in your question (not a URL with your code) and if you can represent your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you find a solution ?